# Problema com Laravel 5.5 - Rotas API

Tags: php, laravel

tudo bem?

Estou novamente aqui com um novo problema... estou usando o Laravel 5.5 e nesse processo estou com problemas nas rotas usando o middleware da API.

Para exemplificar, meu arquivo web.php está da seguinte maneira

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['cors', 'api'], 'prefix' => 'api'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Jobs API', 'status' => 'Connected']);;
    });

    Route::post('auth/login', 'AuthController@login');
});
```

Eu estou testando via PostMan as rotas, se eu colocar a rota

```
http://192.168.15.253:8091/sys-pesquisa/public/api/
```

Tenho o seguinte retorno:

```
{
    "message": "Jobs API",
    "status": "Connected"
}
```

Se eu tentar acessar a Rota "POST" (auth/login) recebo a seguinte mensagem:

```
The page has expired due to inactivity. 

Please refresh and try again.
```

Percebi que se alterar de POST para GET deixando..

```
Route::get('auth/login' .........
```

Tenho o retorno positivo:

```
{"result":false,"errors":["The senha field is required.","The usuario field is required."]}
```

Porém como que é uma API que vai ser acessado via aplicativo móvel preciso q seja feito envio via POST.

Enfim, não faço ideia o que pode ser, pesquisei e encontrei algumas coisas falando sobre a classe 'VerifyCsrfToken', inclusive até adicionei esse trecho na classe VerifyCsrfToken:

```
protected $except = [
        'api/*'
    ];
```

Mas não tive sucesso... Alguém pode me ajudar?

Obrigado galera!!!

Comment: Quando você testou o método POST você colocou o prefixo "api"?
O laravel tem configurado por padrão um prefixo em RouteServiceProvider, você pode alterar ou até mesmo removê-lo.